# two table views in one viewcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, tableview

I'm trying to make a pros and cons list in swift, but whenever I delete a con it deletes a pro. I think that it is a problem with index path being linked to both the pros and cons view controller but I don't know how or where I can separate them

```
class prosConsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
@IBOutlet var prosTableViewOutlet: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var consTableViewOutlet: UITableView!



@IBOutlet var tableViewOutlet: UITableView!

var colleges : [NetCollege] = []


@IBOutlet var consTableView: UITableView!
var collegesTwo : [NetCollegeTwo] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if tableView == tableViewOutlet
    {
        return colleges.count
    }
    else
    {
        return collegesTwo.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == tableViewOutlet
    {
        let cell = tableViewOutlet.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellID")  as! tableViewCell
        //the line under maybe?
        let college = colleges[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = college.name


        return cell

    }
    else
    {
        let cellTwo = consTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IDCell")  as! tableViewCell
        let collegeTwo = collegesTwo[indexPath.row]

        cellTwo.textLabel?.text = collegeTwo.conName


        return cellTwo

    }
}



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    editButtonItem().tag = 0

    func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
    }


}




@IBAction func plusButtonTwo(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    let alertTwo = UIAlertController(title: "Add Con", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertTwo.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler
                { (textField) -> Void in
                    textField.placeholder = "Add Con Here"
            }
            let cancelActionTwo = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
            alertTwo.addAction(cancelActionTwo)


            let addActionTwo = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
                let addCollegesTextFieldTwo = (alertTwo.textFields?[0])! as UITextField

                let netCollegeTwo = NetCollegeTwo(nameTwo: addCollegesTextFieldTwo.text!)


                self.collegesTwo.append(netCollegeTwo)
                self.consTableView.reloadData()
            }

            alertTwo.addAction(addActionTwo)
            self.presentViewController(alertTwo, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
@IBAction func onTappedPlusButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Pro", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler
        { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Add Pro Here"
        }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)


    let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        let addCollegesTextField = (alert.textFields?[0])! as UITextField

        let netCollege = NetCollege(name: addCollegesTextField.text!)


        self.colleges.append(netCollege)
        self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
    }

    alert.addAction(addAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    {

            colleges.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableViewOutlet.reloadData()

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement all this in one view controller, you can try this:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    {
        if tableView == tableViewOutlet
        {
           colleges.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
           tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
           collegesTwo.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
           tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case better solution would be to create two classes called like DataSourceOne, DataSourceTwo (or TableViewModelOne, TableViewModelTwo), and implement all related logic there. This even could be two instances of just one class DataSource, depending on what exactly you need. Then you can instantiate those helper classes in `viewDidLoad` and assign  them to `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of your table views. Your will also need to hold strong reference for them somewhere, because `dataSource` and `delegate` properties are week.